# Cannot connect myetherwallet to a geth private chain: (error_33) Could not connect to the node

Tags: private-blockchain, myetherwallet

I follow the MyEtherWallet: [Use Your Own Server Guide](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/226) to use MyEtherWallet on my private ethereum network. I am doing this setup on my node, where my ethereum node runs. My node runs fine, it can mine and connect to other peers.

I get `error 33` when I try to connect to custom node with MEW on my server.

Started the node on my server  like this:

```
nohup sudo geth --port 30304 --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8101 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,utils" --datadir myDataDir --networkid 19720502 --bootnodes="enode:////cf2a1e3bb2cfe5a8aed058b609d6f4c844238e44425a7b24e422ce61cd971257859db2a8c4584acfe9bd65ffbec78d7db5cba14cbf32953f8f5c94e08135b20c@46.231.206.125:30304" &
```

On my server I downloaded MEW 3.11.2 changed `nodeIP.json` and put in the IP adress `46.231.206.125` instead of `x.x.x.x` changed the ports from **8584** to **8101** in the file `response.js` made sure ssl is installed (https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=46.231.206.125).

Switched off apache (because port **80** was busy) using https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/

Then I typed:

`sudo node runServer.js`

it runs without errors however if I try to connect via MEW custom node `https://46.231.206.125` port **8101** clicking on custom and networkid in eip1155

I get

```
(error_33) Could not connect to the node. Refresh your page, try a different node (top-right corner), check your firewall settings. If custom node, check your configs.
```

---

**Question:** What can I do to find out what the problem could be? 
**Question:** Where can I find the source of this error?

---

*Here is some background information:*

However if I do this locally on my machine it all works, I can access the local node when I do this:

change `nodeIP.json` and put in the IP Address `127.0.0.1`, change in `response.js` the ports to **8101**, `sudo node runLocalServer.js` and access it by opening MEW locally and using `http://127.0.0.1` port **8101** clicking on custom and typing in the correct networkid in `eip1155`.

Comment: After you fix problem pointed out by smarx, you might face more problems, because your URL contains IP, but the SSL certificate is issued to domain name. You need to use something like https://rc18jf2201.vpsflex.net:8101/.

Another remark I have - are you sure MEW supports RPC over SSL?

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have SSL set up on port 8101.

http://46.231.206.125:8101 works, but not https://46.231.206.125:8101.

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}' http://46.231.206.125:8101 -H content-type:application/json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0xbd61"}

$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}' https://46.231.206.125:8101 -H content-type:application/json
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Comment: Looks like it. Calling sslanalyzer with explicit port specification ( https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=46.231.206.125:8101) confirms there is no SSL.

Comment: thanks for that. I tried all day to do different things to solve the problem.

If in runServer.js 
i changefrom httpsServer.listen(443) to httpsServer.listen(8101)

then try to run 
sudo node runServer.js

i get the Error
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8101
is there any other place i can make sure SSL is set up for port 8101 ?

Comment: What is `runServer.js`? I don't think you've shared that code, so it's going to be difficult to guess at the problem.

Comment: find the code of runServer.js here https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/tree/mercury/json_relay_node

Comment: I think we're missing part of the story... I don't see any mention of 8101. What's listening on that port?

Comment: i started a ethereum node with:
geth ...... --rpcport 8101 ....
see the very beginning of the post

Comment: You can't launch a new HTTPS server on port 8101 if geth is already listening on that port.